# Postgresql: query on jsonb column - index doesn't make it quicker

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

There is a table in `Postgresql 9.6`, query on `jsonb` column is slow compared to a relational table, and adding a `GIN` index on it doesn't make it quicker.

**Table:**

```
-- create table
create table dummy_jsonb (
    id serial8,
    data jsonb,
    primary key (id)
);

-- create index
CREATE INDEX dummy_jsonb_data_index ON dummy_jsonb USING gin (data);
-- CREATE INDEX dummy_jsonb_data_index ON dummy_jsonb USING gin (data jsonb_path_ops);
```

**Generate data:**

```
-- generate data,
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy_jsonb_gen_data(n integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    i integer:=1;
    name varchar;
    create_at varchar;
    json_str varchar;
BEGIN
    WHILE i<=n LOOP
        name:='dummy_' || i::text;
        create_at:=EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date_trunc('milliseconds', now())) * 1000;
        json_str:='{
                 "name": "' || name || '",
                 "size": ' || i || ',
                 "create_at": ' || create_at || '
               }';

        insert into dummy_jsonb(data) values
        (json_str::jsonb
        );
        i:= i + 1;
    END LOOP;

    return n;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- call function,
select dummy_jsonb_gen_data(1000000);

-- drop function,
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dummy_jsonb_gen_data(integer);
```

**Query:**

```
select * from dummy_jsonb
where data->>'name' like 'dummy_%' and data->>'size' >= '500000'
order by data->>'size' desc
offset 50000 limit 10;
```

**Test result:**

- The query takes 1.8 seconds on a slow vm.
- Adding or removing the index, don't make a difference.
- Changing to index gin with `jsonb_path_ops`, also don't make a difference.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to make the query quicker, either improve index or sql?
- If not, the does it means, within pg a relational table is more proper in this case?
- And, in my test, `mongodb` performs better, does that means mongodb is more proper for such storage & query?

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

> The default GIN operator class for jsonb supports queries with top-level key-exists operators `?`, `?&` and `?|` operators and path/value-exists operator `@>` [...] The non-default GIN operator class jsonb_path_ops supports indexing the `@>` operator only.

Your query uses `LIKE` and string comparison with `>` (which is probably not correct to begin with), neither of those are supported by a GIN index.

But even an index on `(data ->> 'name')` wouldn't be used for the condition `data->>'name' like 'dummy_%'` as that is true for **all** rows because every name starts with `dummy`.

You can create a regular btree index on the name:

```
CREATE INDEX ON dummy_jsonb ( (data ->> 'name') varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Which will be used if the condition is restrictive enough, e.g.:

```
where data->>'name' like 'dummy_9549%'
```

If you need to query for the size, you can create an index on `((data ->> 'size')::int)` and then use something like this:

```
where (data->>'size')::int >= 500000
```

---

However your use of `limit` and `offset` will always force the database to read all rows, sort them and the limit the result. This is never going to be very fast. You might want to read [this article](http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) for more information why limit/offset is not very efficient.

---

JSON is a nice addition to the relational world, but only if you use it appropriately. If you don't need dynamic attributes for a row, then use standard columns and data types. Even though JSON support is Postgres is extremely good, this doesn't mean one should use it for everything, just because it's the current hype. Postgres is still a relational database and should be used as such.

---

Unrelated, but: your function to generate the test data can be simplified to a single SQL statement. You might not have been aware of the `generate_series()` function for things like that:

```
insert into dummy_jsonb(data)
select jsonb_build_object('name', 'dummy_'||i, 
                          'size', i::text, 
                          'created_at', (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date_trunc('milliseconds', clock_timestamp())) * 1000)::text)
from generate_series(1,1000000) as t(i);
```

Comment: Learned a ton from this.

Answer (score 3):

While a `btree` index (the standard PostgreSQL index based on binary trees) is able to optimize ordering-based queries like `>= '500000'`, the `gin` index, using an *inverted index* structure, is meant to quickly find data containing specific elements (it is quite used e.g. for text search to find rows containing given words), so (AFAIK) it can't be used for the query you provide.

[PostgreSQL docs on jsonb indexing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) indicates on which `WHERE` conditions the index may be applied. As pointed out there, you can **create a `btree` index on specific elements** in a jsonb column: indexes on the specific elements referenced in the `WHERE` clause should work for the query you indicate.

Also, as commented above, think whether you actually need JSON for your use case.

Comment: Thx, guess framework like `lucene` use index similar as `GIN` a lot.