# Improving performance of Postgres jsonb queries combined with relational queries

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, jsonb, postgresql-12

I have a single SELECT that queries both regular postgres tables and a jsonb column.
When I SELECT the entire jsonb column, the query is fast (574 ms).
However when I instead select a top-level path of the same jsonb column, the query slows down by 6x (3241ms). My final query needs to access the string array values from 4 of these top-level jsonb paths, which slows the query right down to 5 seconds.

I have about 50K records in the `cfiles` table and the jsonb column `cfiles.property_values` is structured like this:

```json
{
 "Sample Names":["up to 200 short strings..."],
 "Project IDs": ["up to 10 short strings..."],
 "Run IDs":     ["up to 10 short strings..."],
 "Data Type":   ["up to 10 short strings..."]
}
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092484/postgresql-query-on-jsonb-column-index-doesnt-make-it-quicker) answer I tried adding a GIN index below but it had very little effect (run time in comments below), I'm assuming because my query is not pure json using the `@>` operator and is combined with a relational query.

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON cfiles USING GIN (property_values jsonb_path_ops);
```

I'm surprised at the huge difference in getting the whole column vs querying even just the top-level json keys. At this point, it seems more performant to fetch the whole jsonb column as a string and split it on the commas and chomp the quotes, which is a hack I'd prefer to avoid.

I'm aiming for <2000ms - are there any other ways I can improve the performance? (query, table and explain below) - **Update:** Using PostgreSQL Version 12

```sql
SELECT
-- FAST OPTION: getting all of json: no GIN=579ms; with GIN=574ms
cfiles.property_values as "1907",
-- == vs ==
-- SLOW OPTION: getting a json path: no GIN=3273ms; with GIN=3241ms
cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Sample Names"}' as "1907",
-- adding another path: with GIN=4028ms
cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Project IDs"}' as "1908",
-- adding yet another path: with GIN=4774ms
cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Run IDs"}' as "1909",
-- adding yet another path: with GIN=5558ms
cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Data Type"}' as "1910",
-- ==== rest of query below I can't change ====
user_permissions.notified_at::text as "111",
group_permissions.notified_at::text as "112",
user_permissions.task_id::text as "113",
group_permissions.task_id::text as "114",
datasets.id as "151",
datasets.name as "154",
datasets.path as "155",
datasets.last_modified as "156",
datasets.file_count as "157",
datasets.locked as "158",
datasets.content_types as "159",
cfiles.name as "105",
cfiles.last_modified as "107",
pg_size_pretty(cfiles.size::bigint) as "106",
cfiles.id as "101",
cfiles.tid as "102",
cfiles.uuid as "103",
cfiles.path as "104",
cfiles.content_type as "108",
cfiles.locked as "109",
cfiles.checksum as "110"
FROM cfiles
JOIN datasets ON datasets.id=cfiles.dataset_id
LEFT JOIN user_permissions ON (user_permissions.cfile_id=cfiles.id OR user_permissions.dataset_id=datasets.id)
LEFT JOIN users on users.id=user_permissions.user_id
LEFT JOIN group_permissions ON (group_permissions.cfile_id=cfiles.id OR group_permissions.dataset_id=datasets.id)
LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id=group_permissions.group_id
LEFT JOIN user_groups ON groups.id=user_groups.group_id
LEFT JOIN picklist_cfiles ON picklist_cfiles.cfile_id=cfiles.id
WHERE
cfiles.tid=5
ORDER BY "107" desc
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0
```

```
                                           Table "public.cfiles"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |              Default               
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id              | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('cfiles_id_seq'::regclass)
 tid             | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 uuid            | uuid                        |           | not null | gen_random_uuid()
 dataset_id      | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 path            | character varying           |           | not null | 
 name            | character varying           |           |          | 
 checksum        | character varying           |           |          | 
 size            | bigint                      |           |          | 
 last_modified   | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 content_type    | character varying           |           |          | 
 locked          | boolean                     |           | not null | false
 property_values | jsonb                       |           |          | 
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "cfiles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "cfiles_property_values_idx" gin (property_values jsonb_path_ops)
    "index_cfiles_dataset_id_path" UNIQUE, btree (dataset_id, path)
    "index_cfiles_name" btree (name)
    "index_cfiles_tid" btree (tid)
    "index_cfiles_uuid_id_path" UNIQUE, btree (uuid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "cfiles_datasets_fk" FOREIGN KEY (dataset_id) REFERENCES datasets(id)
    "cfiles_tenants_fk" FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES tenants(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "group_permissions" CONSTRAINT "group_permissions_cfiles_fk" FOREIGN KEY (cfile_id) REFERENCES cfiles(id)
    TABLE "picklist_cfiles" CONSTRAINT "picklist_cfiles_cfiles_fk" FOREIGN KEY (cfile_id) REFERENCES cfiles(id)
    TABLE "user_permissions" CONSTRAINT "user_permissions_cfiles_fk" FOREIGN KEY (cfile_id) REFERENCES cfiles(id)
```

Slow query plan:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=13700.06..13700.11 rows=20 width=662) (actual time=5702.511..5702.521 rows=20 loops=1)
   Output: ((cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Sample Names"}'::text[])), ((cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Project IDs"}'::text[])), ((cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Run IDs"}'::text[])), ((cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Data Type"}'::text[])), ((user_permissions.notified_at)::text), ((group_permissions.notified_at)::text), ((user_permissions.task_id)::text), ((group_permissions.task_id)::text), datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, (pg_size_pretty(cfiles.size)), cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum
   ->  Sort  (cost=13700.06..13810.61 rows=44219 width=662) (actual time=5702.508..5702.512 rows=20 loops=1)
         Output: ((cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Sample Names"}'::text[])), ((cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Project IDs"}'::text[])), ((cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Run IDs"}'::text[])), ((cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Data Type"}'::text[])), ((user_permissions.notified_at)::text), ((group_permissions.notified_at)::text), ((user_permissions.task_id)::text), ((group_permissions.task_id)::text), datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, (pg_size_pretty(cfiles.size)), cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum
         Sort Key: cfiles.last_modified DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 344kB
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=39.53..12523.41 rows=44219 width=662) (actual time=2.535..5526.409 rows=44255 loops=1)
               Output: (cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Sample Names"}'::text[]), (cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Project IDs"}'::text[]), (cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Run IDs"}'::text[]), (cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Data Type"}'::text[]), (user_permissions.notified_at)::text, (group_permissions.notified_at)::text, (user_permissions.task_id)::text, (group_permissions.task_id)::text, datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, pg_size_pretty(cfiles.size), cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum
               Hash Cond: (cfiles.id = picklist_cfiles.cfile_id)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=38.19..10918.99 rows=44219 width=867) (actual time=1.639..632.739 rows=44255 loops=1)
                     Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.size, cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum, datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types, user_permissions.notified_at, user_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id
                     Join Filter: ((user_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.id) OR (user_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.id))
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 177020
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=38.19..7822.61 rows=44219 width=851) (actual time=1.591..464.449 rows=44255 loops=1)
                           Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.size, cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum, datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types, group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id
                           Join Filter: ((group_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.id) OR (group_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.id))
                           Rows Removed by Join Filter: 354040
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=35.75..4723.32 rows=44219 width=835) (actual time=1.301..163.411 rows=44255 loops=1)
                                 Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.size, cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum, datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types
                                 Inner Unique: true
                                 Hash Cond: (cfiles.dataset_id = datasets.id)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on public.cfiles  (cost=0.00..4570.70 rows=44219 width=644) (actual time=0.044..49.425 rows=44255 loops=1)
                                       Output: cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.dataset_id, cfiles.path, cfiles.name, cfiles.checksum, cfiles.size, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.property_values, cfiles.created_at, cfiles.updated_at
                                       Filter: (cfiles.tid = 5)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 1561
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=28.11..28.11 rows=611 width=199) (actual time=1.234..1.235 rows=611 loops=1)
                                       Output: datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types
                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 149kB
                                       ->  Seq Scan on public.datasets  (cost=0.00..28.11 rows=611 width=199) (actual time=0.012..0.571 rows=611 loops=1)
                                             Output: datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types
                           ->  Materialize  (cost=2.44..3.97 rows=4 width=32) (actual time=0.000..0.002 rows=8 loops=44255)
                                 Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id
                                 ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=2.44..3.95 rows=4 width=32) (actual time=0.170..0.248 rows=8 loops=1)
                                       Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id
                                       Hash Cond: (user_groups.group_id = groups.id)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on public.user_groups  (cost=0.00..1.34 rows=34 width=8) (actual time=0.022..0.056 rows=34 loops=1)
                                             Output: user_groups.id, user_groups.tid, user_groups.user_id, user_groups.group_id, user_groups.created_at, user_groups.updated_at
                                       ->  Hash  (cost=2.39..2.39 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.121..0.121 rows=4 loops=1)
                                             Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.id
                                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                             ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.09..2.39 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.063..0.092 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                   Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.id
                                                   Hash Cond: (groups.id = group_permissions.group_id)
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on public.groups  (cost=0.00..1.19 rows=19 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.017 rows=19 loops=1)
                                                         Output: groups.id, groups.tid, groups.name, groups.description, groups.default_uview, groups.created_at, groups.updated_at
                                                   ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.032..0.033 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                         Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, group_permissions.group_id
                                                         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on public.group_permissions  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.017..0.022 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                               Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, group_permissions.group_id
                     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=4 loops=44255)
                           Output: user_permissions.notified_at, user_permissions.task_id, user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, user_permissions.user_id
                           ->  Seq Scan on public.user_permissions  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.021..0.025 rows=4 loops=1)
                                 Output: user_permissions.notified_at, user_permissions.task_id, user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, user_permissions.user_id
               ->  Hash  (cost=1.15..1.15 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.040..0.040 rows=15 loops=1)
                     Output: picklist_cfiles.cfile_id
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on public.picklist_cfiles  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.017 rows=15 loops=1)
                           Output: picklist_cfiles.cfile_id
 Planning Time: 3.141 ms
 Execution Time: 5702.799 ms
(61 rows)
```

**Update:** Refactorng to CTE pattern got me down to 20ms

```sql
WITH T as (
    select cfiles.property_values as prop_vals,
    user_permissions.notified_at::text as "111",
    group_permissions.notified_at::text as "112",
    user_permissions.task_id::text as "113",
    group_permissions.task_id::text as "114",
    datasets.id as "151",
    datasets.name as "154",
    datasets.path as "155",
    datasets.last_modified as "156",
    datasets.file_count as "157",
    datasets.locked as "158",
    datasets.content_types as "159",
    cfiles.name as "105",
    cfiles.last_modified as "107",
    pg_size_pretty(cfiles.size::bigint) as "106",
    cfiles.id as "101",
    cfiles.tid as "102",
    cfiles.uuid as "103",
    cfiles.path as "104",
    cfiles.content_type as "108",
    cfiles.locked as "109",
    cfiles.checksum as "110"
    FROM cfiles
    JOIN datasets ON datasets.id=cfiles.dataset_id
    LEFT JOIN user_permissions ON (user_permissions.cfile_id=cfiles.id OR user_permissions.dataset_id=datasets.id)
    LEFT JOIN users on users.id=user_permissions.user_id
    LEFT JOIN group_permissions ON (group_permissions.cfile_id=cfiles.id OR group_permissions.dataset_id=datasets.id)
    LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id=group_permissions.group_id
    LEFT JOIN user_groups ON groups.id=user_groups.group_id
    LEFT JOIN picklist_cfiles ON picklist_cfiles.cfile_id=cfiles.id
    WHERE
    cfiles.tid=5
    LIMIT 20
) 
SELECT
prop_vals ->> 'Sample Names' as "1907",
prop_vals ->> 'Project IDs' as "1908",
prop_vals ->> 'Run IDs' as "1909",
prop_vals ->> 'Data Type' as "1910",
"111", "112", "113", "114", "151", "154", "155", "156", "157",
"158", "159", "105", "107", "106", "101", "102", "103", "104",
"108", "109", "110"
FROM T
ORDER BY "107" desc;
```

CTE query plan:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=16.18..16.23 rows=20 width=662) (actual time=18.771..18.779 rows=20 loops=1)
   Output: ((t.prop_vals ->> 'Sample Names'::text)), ((t.prop_vals ->> 'Project IDs'::text)), ((t.prop_vals ->> 'Run IDs'::text)), ((t.prop_vals ->> 'Data Type'::text)), t."111", t."112", t."113", t."114", t."151", t."154", t."155", t."156", t."157", t."158", t."159", t."105", t."107", t."106", t."101", t."102", t."103", t."104", t."108", t."109", t."110"
   Sort Key: t."107" DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 368kB
   ->  Subquery Scan on t  (cost=4.05..15.74 rows=20 width=662) (actual time=1.091..18.412 rows=20 loops=1)
         Output: (t.prop_vals ->> 'Sample Names'::text), (t.prop_vals ->> 'Project IDs'::text), (t.prop_vals ->> 'Run IDs'::text), (t.prop_vals ->> 'Data Type'::text), t."111", t."112", t."113", t."114", t."151", t."154", t."155", t."156", t."157", t."158", t."159", t."105", t."107", t."106", t."101", t."102", t."103", t."104", t."108", t."109", t."110"
         ->  Limit  (cost=4.05..15.34 rows=20 width=987) (actual time=0.320..1.241 rows=20 loops=1)
               Output: cfiles.property_values, ((user_permissions.notified_at)::text), ((group_permissions.notified_at)::text), ((user_permissions.task_id)::text), ((group_permissions.task_id)::text), datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, (pg_size_pretty(cfiles.size)), cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.05..24965.23 rows=44219 width=987) (actual time=0.318..1.224 rows=20 loops=1)
                     Output: cfiles.property_values, (user_permissions.notified_at)::text, (group_permissions.notified_at)::text, (user_permissions.task_id)::text, (group_permissions.task_id)::text, datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, pg_size_pretty(cfiles.size), cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum
                     Join Filter: ((user_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.id) OR (user_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.id))
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 80
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.05..20873.92 rows=44219 width=851) (actual time=0.273..1.056 rows=20 loops=1)
                           Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.size, cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum, datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types, group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id
                           Join Filter: ((group_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.id) OR (group_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.id))
                           Rows Removed by Join Filter: 160
                           ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.61..17774.63 rows=44219 width=835) (actual time=0.125..0.745 rows=20 loops=1)
                                 Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.size, cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum, datasets.id, datasets.name, datasets.path, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.locked, datasets.content_types
                                 Inner Unique: true
                                 ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1.34..4738.00 rows=44219 width=644) (actual time=0.094..0.475 rows=20 loops=1)
                                       Output: cfiles.property_values, cfiles.name, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.size, cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.path, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.checksum, cfiles.dataset_id
                                       Hash Cond: (cfiles.id = picklist_cfiles.cfile_id)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on public.cfiles  (cost=0.00..4570.70 rows=44219 width=644) (actual time=0.046..0.360 rows=20 loops=1)
                                             Output: cfiles.id, cfiles.tid, cfiles.uuid, cfiles.dataset_id, cfiles.path, cfiles.name, cfiles.checksum, cfiles.size, cfiles.last_modified, cfiles.content_type, cfiles.locked, cfiles.property_values, cfiles.created_at, cfiles.updated_at
                                             Filter: (cfiles.tid = 5)
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 629
                                       ->  Hash  (cost=1.15..1.15 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.034..0.035 rows=15 loops=1)
                                             Output: picklist_cfiles.cfile_id
                                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                             ->  Seq Scan on public.picklist_cfiles  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=15 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.018 rows=15 loops=1)
                                                   Output: picklist_cfiles.cfile_id
                                 ->  Index Scan using datasets_pkey on public.datasets  (cost=0.28..0.29 rows=1 width=199) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=20)
                                       Output: datasets.id, datasets.tid, datasets.bucket_path_id, datasets.path, datasets.name, datasets.last_modified, datasets.file_count, datasets.size, datasets.content_types, datasets.locked, datasets.created_at, datasets.updated_at
                                       Index Cond: (datasets.id = cfiles.dataset_id)
                           ->  Materialize  (cost=2.44..3.97 rows=4 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.009 rows=8 loops=20)
                                 Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id
                                 ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=2.44..3.95 rows=4 width=32) (actual time=0.088..0.122 rows=8 loops=1)
                                       Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id
                                       Hash Cond: (user_groups.group_id = groups.id)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on public.user_groups  (cost=0.00..1.34 rows=34 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.016 rows=34 loops=1)
                                             Output: user_groups.id, user_groups.tid, user_groups.user_id, user_groups.group_id, user_groups.created_at, user_groups.updated_at
                                       ->  Hash  (cost=2.39..2.39 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.069..0.069 rows=4 loops=1)
                                             Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.id
                                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                             ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.09..2.39 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.043..0.064 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                   Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, groups.id
                                                   Hash Cond: (groups.id = group_permissions.group_id)
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on public.groups  (cost=0.00..1.19 rows=19 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.011 rows=19 loops=1)
                                                         Output: groups.id, groups.tid, groups.name, groups.description, groups.default_uview, groups.created_at, groups.updated_at
                                                   ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                         Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, group_permissions.group_id
                                                         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on public.group_permissions  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.009..0.014 rows=4 loops=1)
                                                               Output: group_permissions.notified_at, group_permissions.task_id, group_permissions.cfile_id, group_permissions.dataset_id, group_permissions.group_id
                     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=4 loops=20)
                           Output: user_permissions.notified_at, user_permissions.task_id, user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, user_permissions.user_id
                           ->  Seq Scan on public.user_permissions  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=40) (actual time=0.018..0.022 rows=4 loops=1)
                                 Output: user_permissions.notified_at, user_permissions.task_id, user_permissions.cfile_id, user_permissions.dataset_id, user_permissions.user_id
 Planning Time: 4.049 ms
 Execution Time: 19.128 ms
(60 rows)
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for taking a look - yep I tried both `->` and `->>` operators and there was no difference. Just added fast execution plan above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slow query is deTOASTing the large jsonb data for all 44255 rows, and then carrying the parsed-out values through the sort to pick out the top 20 rows.  (I don't know why it does the deTOASTing eagerly like that).  So 44235 JSONB were deTOASTed just to be thrown away.

Your fast query is (presumably) returning TOAST pointers from the hash join, sorting the rows with those small pointers, and then deTOASTing only the 20 survivors.  In the case of EXPLAIN ANALYZE, it doesn't even deTOAST the survivors, it just throws the pointers away.

That is the "why", as for what to do about it, if you truly can't alter any of the query below the very top part, I doubt there is anything you can do about it on the server side.

If you can modify the query more substantially, then you can improve the run time with a CTE.  Have the CTE select the entire jsonb, and then the select on the CTE pulls the value out of it.

```
WITH T as (select cfiles.property_values as "1907", <rest of query>) 
SELECT "1907"->>'name1', "1907"->>'name2', <rest of select list> from T;
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is an old PostgreSQL version. Since 9.6, `SELECT` list entries are evaluated after sorting.

Comment: @jjanes thanks I hadn't heard of TOAST - if I was able to edit any/all of the query, is there a way to deTOAST only the survivors but still have them assigned to column names?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe just updated - this is PostgreSQL version 12

Comment: @jjanes thanks - using CTE format got me down to 17ms with minimal changes to the original query

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @jjanes already said, you could first limit the amount of records to just 20 records, and then doing the rest of your work. Something like this:

```
WITH i(id) AS (
    -- core piece of SQL to select the records you're looking for
    SELECT
        cfiles.ID 
    FROM
        cfiles
        JOIN datasets ON datasets.ID = cfiles.dataset_id 
    WHERE
        cfiles.tid = 5
    ORDER BY
        cfiles.last_modified DESC 
        LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0 
    ) 
SELECT-- FAST OPTION: getting all of json: no GIN=579ms; with GIN=574ms
    cfiles.property_values AS "1907",
-- == vs ==
-- SLOW OPTION: getting a json path: no GIN=3273ms; with GIN=3241ms
    cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Sample Names"}' AS "1907",
-- adding another path: with GIN=4028ms
    cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Project IDs"}' AS "1908",
-- adding yet another path: with GIN=4774ms
    cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Run IDs"}' AS "1909",
-- adding yet another path: with GIN=5558ms
    cfiles.property_values #>> '{"Data Type"}' AS "1910",
-- ==== rest of query below I can't change ====
    user_permissions.notified_at :: TEXT AS "101",
    group_permissions.notified_at :: TEXT AS "102",
    user_permissions.task_id :: TEXT AS "103",
    group_permissions.task_id :: TEXT AS "104",
    datasets.ID AS "151",
    datasets.NAME AS "154",
    datasets.PATH AS "155",
    datasets.last_modified AS "156",
    datasets.file_count AS "157",
    datasets.locked AS "158",
    datasets.content_types AS "159",
    cfiles.NAME AS "105",
    cfiles.last_modified AS "107",
    pg_size_pretty ( cfiles.SIZE :: BIGINT ) AS "106",
    cfiles.ID AS "101",
    cfiles.tid AS "102",
    cfiles.uuid AS "103",
    cfiles.PATH AS "104",
    cfiles.content_type AS "108",
    cfiles.locked AS "109",
    cfiles.checksum AS "110" 
FROM
    cfiles
    JOIN i USING(id) -- should match just 20 records
    JOIN datasets ON datasets.ID = cfiles.dataset_id
    LEFT JOIN user_permissions ON ( user_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.ID OR user_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.ID )
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.ID = user_permissions.user_id
    LEFT JOIN group_permissions ON ( group_permissions.cfile_id = cfiles.ID OR group_permissions.dataset_id = datasets.ID )
    LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.ID = group_permissions.group_id
    LEFT JOIN user_groups ON groups.ID = user_groups.group_id
    LEFT JOIN picklist_cfiles ON picklist_cfiles.cfile_id = cfiles.ID 
ORDER BY
    "107" DESC;
```

You might want to rewrite both LEFT JOIN's that have an OR-condition, you could use a sub query using a UNION ALL. This might speed up thing a little more

Comment: wow this got it down to 60ms thanks - will have to try re-working entire query

Comment: @simj: Could you show us the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE ? Always interesting to see what the database is doing